# QT Creator, syntax checking for c++11

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator

How to turn off error highlighting (red wave under the code) for c++11 cycle range-based operators like that?

```
int myint[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
for (auto x : myint){/**/}
```

Hover prompt shows "unexpected token `:`". The code compiles perfectly.

Another issue - the autocomplete doesn't show `unique_ptr` in `std::` namespace, though compiles OK.

- Qt Creator 2.4.0  Based on Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit) Built on Dec 12 2011 at
  01:10:32

Comment: You would probably have to shut it off globally to get rid of it. Qt Creator probably doesn't know C++11 syntax. Alternatively, you may find an option to set it to C++11 mode.

Comment: It knows auto, unique_ptr and even lambdas. I mean no red waves and compiles good.

Comment: That doesn't mean it knows range-based `for` syntax.

Comment: It means it knows about c++11 features so no any additional option for c++11 mode, I believe.

Comment: It knows some features doesn't mean it knows all of them, does it? :) None of the compilers out there supports all C++11 features yet. And this is just a code model parser.

Comment: Right, what I'm talking about. May be there is a way to change or upgrade a code model parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're writing in C++11 you should change from using QT Creator as the IDE to using Eclipse CDT.  At least this is how I solved this problem.  QT Creator doesn't seem to have any way to customize this real-time syntax checking.  Eclipse on the other hand is extensively customizable in this regard.

**Update:** I think that QtCreator has improved its support for newer versions of C++ since this answer was given, so it is no longer correct.  I can't delete it as it is an accepted answer.

Comment: I should note here that I tried QT Creator again recently and its C++11 support appears to have improved.  I don't recall if this specific problem was fixed though.

Comment: I was about to downvote but noticed the Update part. I think it'd be better if placed above the original answer: not everyone is attentive enough to avoid downvoting without reading the whole post.

Answer (score 10):

I don't understand the line of reasoning in Andrew's answer. Why would *customizing* syntax checking make sense? The syntax is either correct given the context set by the compiler command line, or it is wrong. If it is wrong, it should be marked as such, if not, not. If correct code is marked as wrong, it is a bug, or at least unsupported feature, in the IDE, and it needs a fix, not "customization".

Having said that, the cited example

```
    int myint[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    for (auto x : myint){/**/}
```

works fine here (fairly recent build from master branch).

Regarding the other comment on Kate: Kate's syntax highlighting is used by Qt Creator as fallback in cases where there is no more specific syntax highlighting available for a file. In the case of C++ (98/03/11) there is a real code model used, not Kate's definitions.

Answer (score 5):

There is "syntax highlighting" (coloring) and there is "syntax checking" (wavy underlines).  The syntax coloring does seem to be related to Kate as @Koying suggests, you can modify the colors and turn it off.  As of Qt Creator 2.5.0 it doesn't seem to have a problem with *most* C++11 examples I paste off the web, although your example does indeed still have the underline:

http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2012/05/09/qt-creator-2-5-0-released/

Also unfortunately, at the time of writing (June 13th 2012, which is about a month after the release) the latest integrated SDK package is still installing Qt Creator 2.4.1 by default. :-/

If this is the boat someone is in and wants to try the latest, ***don't do what I did*** by wiping out your Qt SDK install using `/opt/QtSDK/SDKMaintenanceTool`!  That wasted time on a reinstall, after which I executed a `sudo rm -r /opt/QtSDK/QtCreator`, then told the new Qt Creator release to install to `/opt/QtSDK/QtCreator`.  I'll update this post if I hit a snag with that choice!

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Creator_Releases

**BUT** though it seems to work with many C++11 constructs it does nothing for your example nor the particular case I tripped across, which is the `unspaced<nested<syntax>>` for templates.

*(Note: It may seem like a minor thing, but it's a big C++11 feature for me.  I *hate* dealing with having to do `tailspaced<nested<syntax> >`...which led me to always do `fullyspaced< nested< syntax > >` on **all** templates to keep things consistent.  Even simple cases like `vector< int >`.  Now that they fixed the compiler, I'm ready to kill all of that whitespace noise.)*

There doesn't seem to be any way to turn off the wavy underlines ([unless you recompile Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/16774)??).

```
in qt-creator-2.5.0-src\src\plugins\cpptools\cppmodelmanager.cpp:

        QTextCharFormat errorFormat;
        /* disable error underline
        errorFormat.setUnderlineStyle(QTextCharFormat::WaveUnderline);
        errorFormat.setUnderlineColor(Qt::red);
        */

        // set up the format for the warnings.
        QTextCharFormat warningFormat;
        /* disable warning underline
        warningFormat.setUnderlineStyle(QTextCharFormat::WaveUnderline);
        warningFormat.setUnderlineColor(Qt::darkYellow);
        */
```

Either way, it's an insane consequence of duplicating the work of the compiler in the IDE instead of having the two share front-end code.  We live in the dark ages of software. Won't someone [save us](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/IntentionalSoftware.html)?  [/rant]

Here's some of the relevant code (I think):

https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/master/src/plugins/cppeditor/cpphighlighter.cpp

...and the lexer here, note the member `_cxx0xEnabled`:

https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/master/src/libs/cplusplus/SimpleLexer.cpp#line80

Besides your for syntax, the template spacing is the only thing I've found in C++11 that causes the lines.  That's major enough to me that I might just build my own QtCreator to address it!

Answer (score 0):

Qt Creator is using the syntax highlighting definitions from the **Kate** editor (from KDE). See Tools-Options-Text Editor-Generic Highlighter.

If Kate has a definition for c++11, you can use it or you can develop your own.

Comment: Highlighting is OK, `for` and `auto` are bold as usual for keywords. Parsing is wrong.

Comment: Kate syntax highlighting also handle, well, syntax, not only keywords. Easiest is probably to take the one from c++ and tweak it.

Comment: Though I'm not sure about that, because I've red article about Clang was engaging by QT Creator for a code model serving.

Answer (score 0):

Using MSVC compiler, you need to add the line:

```
 /std:c++11
```

To your project's `project.cxxflags` configuration file, where `project` must be replaced by the name of your project. This file is located at the root of your project directory, you may have to create it if it does not already exist.

Remark: this setting is a [MSVC parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version) so the syntax would likely be different for other compilers.

Tested with Qt Creator 4.15.0-rc1 (April 2021) and Visual Studio 2017 on Windows, where the error:

```
`error: no member named 'optional' in namespace 'std'` when trying to use std::optional from header <optional>
```

disappear when adding `/std:c++17` (std::optional was added in C++17).