# C++11 IDE support in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [QT Creator, syntax checking for c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560156/qt-creator-syntax-checking-for-c11)

Is there any way to get C++11 autocompletion working in Qt creator? I added the following two lines to my `.pro` file, but autocompletion still doesn't work (though the code does compile correctly).

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += "-std=c++11"
CXXFLAGS="-std=c++0x"
```

Below is some code I was writing. It builds and runs correctly. But when I type in `std::` and press the autocomplete key, `std::unique_ptr` does not show up on the completion list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> i(new int);
    *i = 1237;

    std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In addition, the syntax-completion doesn't seem to be working for C++11. Here's a screenshot I took.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xsEO.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560156/qt-creator-syntax-checking-for-c11

Answer (score 4):

Qt Creator does not fully support C++11 syntax yet. It supports some stuff, but not everything. Also, it has trouble with templates. It gets better with every new version though, and there's some work going on to switch from the current parse system to LLVM/Clang.

There's nothing you can do configuration-wise. The only thing you can do is making sure to use the latest version (2.6.0 right now.)

Comment: I am currently using 2.6.0. Do you know if the any of the alpha/beta builds has better C++11 support?

Comment: @NealP I don't know. 2.6.0 was released very recently though, so I don't think there's a huge difference between the latest development sources and the released version.